# how do i start PC webcam in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to use webcam in matlab but display error 
code:

```
x=videoinput('Winvideo',1);
```

error message

```
There are no devices installed for the specified
```

what should i do?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you haven't installed support package for webcam. Type `webcamlist` in command window to test this. You'll probably see

```
Error using webcamlist (line 20)
MATLAB Support Package for Webcams has not been installed. Open Support Package Installer to install the Webcam Support Package.
```

There's a hyperlink in the error message, just click on it. It'll guide you through download and installation, then you can use webcam.

Comment: i type 'webcamlist' in command window but re-error massage  Attempt to execute SCRIPT webcam as a function:
C:\Users\Css-PC\Documents\MATLAB\webcam.m

Comment: Is this webcam.m  your own script? Seems like you're overriding some built-in function. Try renaming this one.

Comment: It was further explained؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟